# Can I import a python module from a string in memory?

Tags: python

I have a string of a python module stored in a variable (creds) that looks like this:

```
MY_API_KEY = "DerP12312"
ANOTHER_KEY = "123453)"
```

(Many more lines than just the 2, but all the same convention)

I'd like to import the values of that module into another class like so:

```
from creds import MY_API_KEY
```

A limitation is that I cannot write these contents to local storage. 
(I'd prefer not to do string disection based on `/n` and `=`)

Can I import these values directly from memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) function to execute a string of Python source code (by default it's executed in the current scope so those variables will be set globally):

```
>>> exec('MY_API_KEY = "DerP12312"\nANOTHER_KEY = "123453)"\n')
>>> MY_API_KEY
'DerP12312'
>>> ANOTHER_KEY
'123453)'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I control the contents of the imported file, so no concerns about allowing it to exec in code.

Comment: Cool. If you control the contents of the file, you might also want to consider using a configuration file format like INI (via [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)).